# Максимальный размер сцены JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Пытаюсь в Scene Builder 8.3.0 установить на главную "AnchorPane" максимальный и минимальный размер, но при запуске программы всё равно сцена может уменьшаться и растягиваться до параметров всего монитора.
[image: Скриншот установленных параметров в Scene Builder]

Answer (score 0):

```
stage.setResizable(false);
```

Как же мне надоело находить ответы спустя минуту после заданного вопроса!
http://www.cyberforum.ru/java-gui-javafx/thread1189966.html